# TeamCity installed successfully, but unable to restart after shutdown

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have managed to install TeamCity successfully, with a BuildAgent running.

However, after running runall stop, followed by runall start, I get the following error:

```
error in script file line: 41 file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (Access is denied) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/buildserver.data
SQL exception: error in script file line: 41 file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (Access is denied) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/buildserver.data
```

The file exists in the directory What could be the issue?

I am using TeamCity 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is one of folder permissions which causes me to suspect that the user that the TeamCity Windows service runs as doesn't have read/write access to the folder where you chose to store your TeamCity data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for my local windows installation. The solution is easy run startup.but script as administrator.

Comment: running as administrator is never a solution

Answer (score -1):

The answer is the oldest trick in the book..

After restarting the computer, it works.